# Using Regex to extract part of a string from a HTML/text file

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# regular expression to match author names in a text document that is written as:

```
"author":"AUTHOR'S NAME"
```

The regex is as follows:

```
new Regex("\"author\":\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\\s?[A-Za-z0-9]*")
```

This returns `"author":"AUTHOR'S NAME`. However, I don't want the quotation marks or the word `Author` before. I just want the name.

Could anyone help me get the expected value please?

Comment: Can you post the author content as it appears within the text document?

Comment: Unrelated, but your expression matches only a subset of names. It doesn't allow for any special characters, such as the `'` in `O'Connor` and it only allows for exactly one space, no hyphens, no foreign characters etc. I don't know your usecase, but if you know the author name is going to be enclosed within the quotes, you would get away with just accepting anything that isn't a double quotes: `\"author\":\"([^\"]+)\"`.

Comment: Thanks David. Good point I hadn't considered. Gibbs, the author's name(s) will appear after the text I've managed to find in quotation marks, as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex groups to get a part of the string. `( )` acts as a capture group and can be accessed by the `.Groups` field.

`.Groups[0]` matches the whole string

`.Groups[1]` matches the first group (and so on)

```
string pattern = "\"author\":\"([A-Za-z0-9]*\\s?[A-Za-z0-9]*)\"";
var match = Regex.Match("\"author\":\"Name123\"", pattern);
string authorName = match.Groups[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use look-around approach to only get a match value:

```
var txt = "\"author\":\"AUTHOR'S NAME\"";
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=""author"":"")[^""]+(?="")");
var result = rgx.Match(txt).Value;
```

My regex yields 555,020 iterations per second speed with this input string, which should suffice.

`result` will be `AUTHOR'S NAME`.

`(?<="author":")` checks if we have `"author":"` before the match, `[^"]+` looks safe since you only want to match alphanumerics and space between the quotes, and `(?=")` is checking the trailing quote.

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need more assistance?

Comment: Not at my computer right now, will let you know when I am.

Comment: Sorry to bother, did you have time to check my approach? BTW, if there can be spaces around `:`, we can enhance the look-behind as `@"(?<=""author""\s*:\s*"")[^""]+(?="")"`.